# How to calculate weighted similarity with scipy.spatial.distance.cosine?

Tags: python, math, machine-learning, euclidean-distance, cosine-similarity

From the function definition:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html

scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(u, v, w=None)

but my codes got some errors:

```
from scipy import spatial
d1 = [3,5,5,3,3,2]
d2 = [1,1,3,1,3,2]
weight_of_importance = [0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.1,0.3]

result = spatial.distance.cosine(d1, d2, weight_of_importance)
print(result)
```

TypeError: cosine() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

It works when I only input 2 parameters.
But those features got different weighting of importance.
How could I calculate the similarity with weighted importance for d1 and d2?

Comment: it works correctly in scipy 1.1.0. What is your version?

Comment: It works in scipy 1.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this parameter has been added in [SciPy v1.0.0](http://pageperso.lif.univ-mrs.fr/~francois.denis/IAAM1/scipy-html-1.0.0/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html).

This parameter is not there in [the previous version 0.19.1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html)

An excerpt from [SciPy v1.0.0 release notes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.1.0.0.html):

> `scipy.spatial` improvements
>
> Many distance metrics in
>   [scipy.spatial.distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html#module-scipy.spatial.distance)
>   **gained support for weights**.

Comment: Thanks. I was so blur.